# Tensorflow serving object detection client

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-serving

I have a tensorflow serving docker container running a object detector model. To generate this model I have used the following code

```
  input_img = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder:0')
  output_cls_prob = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('Reshape_2:0')
  output_box_pred = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('rpn_bbox_pred/Reshape_1:0')

  builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder('./export/1')

  imageplaceholder_info = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_img)
  cls_prob_info = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(output_cls_prob)
  box_pred_info = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(output_box_pred)
  prediction_signature = (
    tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs={
        'image': imageplaceholder_info
      },
      outputs={
        'output_cls_prob': cls_prob_info,
        'output_box_pred': box_pred_info
      },
      method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME
    )
  )
  init_op = tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
  builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
       signature_def_map={'ctpn_recs_predict': prediction_signature}, legacy_init_op=init_op)
  builder.save()
```

The docker is running this tensorflow serving model on localhost: port 9000. How do I send an image on this port number and get back a appropriate response (in my case output_cls_prob, and output_box_pred) ?

So far I have this grpc client code to read an image:

```
def run(host, port, image, model, signature_name):

    channel = grpc.insecure_channel('{host}:{port}'.format(host=host, port=port))
    stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(channel)


    # Read an image
    data = imread(image)
    data = data.astype(np.float32)
    print(data)




    if __name__ == '__main__':
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('--host', help='Tensorflow server host name', default='localhost', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('--port', help='Tensorflow server port number', default=9000, type=int)
        parser.add_argument('--image', help='input image', type=str, default='1.jpg')
        parser.add_argument('--model', help='model name', type=str, default='serve/test')
        parser.add_argument('--signature_name', help='Signature name of saved TF model',
                            default='prediction_signature', type=str)

        args = parser.parse_args()
        run(args.host, args.port, args.image, args.model, args.signature_name)
```

what should I do so that the image read is sent to tensorflow serving docker container for prediction ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a python script that queries the TF Serving using REST and gets the response from the model.

Please refer to the below blog from tensorflow, where they have mentioned complete details from hosting a TF Serving model in Docker and sending requests for prediction.

https://medium.com/tensorflow/serving-ml-quickly-with-tensorflow-serving-and-docker-7df7094aa008